# Split sentences based on different patterns in Python 3

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, recursion

I need to split strings based on a sequence of Regex patterns. I am able to apply individually the split, but the issue is recursively split the different sentences.

For example I have this sentence:

```
"I want to be splitted using different patterns. It is a complex task, and not easy to solve; so, I would need help."
```

I would need to split the sentence based on ",", ";" and ".".

The resulst should be 5 sentences like:

```
"I want to be splitted using different patterns."
"It is a complex task,"
"and not easy to solve;"
"so,"
"I would need help."
```

My code so far:

```
import re
sample_sentence = "I want to be splitted using different patterns. It is a complex task, and not easy to solve; so, I would need help."
patterns = [re.compile('(?<=\.) '),
            re.compile('(?<=,) '),
            re.compile('(?<=;) ')]
for pattern in patterns:
    splitted_sentences = pattern.split(sample_sentence)
    print(f'Pattern used: {pattern}')
```

How can I apply the different patterns without losing the results and get the expected result?

Edit: I need to run each pattern one by one, as I need to do some checks in the result of every pattern, so running it in some sort of tree algorithm. Sorry for not explaining entirely, in my head it was clear, but I did not think it would have side effects.

Answer (score 3):

You can join each pattern with `|`:

```
import re
s = "I want to be splitted using different patterns. It is a complex task, and not easy to solve; so, I would need help."
result = re.split('(?<=\.)\s|,\s*|;\s*', s)
```

Output:

```
['I want to be splitted using different patterns.', 'It is a complex task', 'and not easy to solve', 'so', 'I would need help.']
```

Answer (score 2):

Python has this in re

Try

```
re.split('; | , | . ',ourString)
```

Comment: This does not generate the correct output, instead, `['I want to be splitted using different patterns. It is', 'complex task, and not easy to solve', 'so,', 'would need help.']`. You should at least escape `.`, `.` alone will match any character, thus, `\s.\s` is attempting to match any character bounded on both sides by a space.

Answer (score 1):

I can't think of a single regex to do this. So, what you can do it replace all the different type of delimiters with a custom-defined delimiter, say **$DELIMITER$** and then split your sentence based on this delimiter.

```
new_sent = re.sub('[.,;]', '$DELIMITER$', sent)
new_sent.split('$DELIMITER$')
```

This will result in the following:

```
['I want to be splitted using different patterns',
 ' It is a complex task',
 ' and not easy to solve',
 ' so',
 ' I would need help',
 '']
```

**NOTE:** The above output has an additional empty string. This is because there is a period at the end of the sentence. To avoid this, you can either remove that empty element from the list or you can substitute the custom defined delimiter **if it occurs** at the end of the sentence.

```
new_sent = re.sub('[.,;]', '$DELIMITER$', sent)
new_sent = re.sub('\$DELIMITER\$$', '', new_sent)
new_sent.split('$DELIMITER$')
```

In case you have a list of delimiters, you can make you regex pattern using the following code:

```
delimiter_list = [',', '.', ':', ';']
pattern = '[' + ''.join(delimiter_list) + ']' #will result in [,.:;]
new_sent = re.sub(pattern, '$DELIMITER$', sent)
new_sent = re.sub('\$DELIMITER\$$', '', new_sent)
new_sent.split('$DELIMITER$')
```

I hope this helps!!!

Answer (score 0):

Use a lookbehind with a character class:

```
import re
s = "I want to be splitted using different patterns. It is a complex task, and not easy to solve; so, I would need help."
result = re.split('(?<=[.,;])\s', s)
print(result)
```

**Output:**

```
['I want to be splitted using different patterns.', 
 'It is a complex task,', 
 'and not easy to solve;',
 'so,', 
 'I would need help.']
```